# UNION query works slow

Tags: t-sql, union, sybase, sap-ase

On an SAP Sybase ASE 15.5 database.

UNION works very slow

```
select col1,col2,col3
from table1(INDEX nn MRU),table2 (INDEX hh MRU)
where key1=key2
UNION
select col1,col2,col3
from table3(INDEX pp MRU),table2 (INDEX ll MRU)
where key4=key3
```

table 1 and 3 are small(10 records each
tables 1 and 4 - are very large (68 mln records each) and I neeed only active records, which we have 1,5 mln in each big table,

Actually, I tried separate queries. The same slow. Even if I purge inactive records or select active record to different table, it still takes long time. Yesterday I rebuild one index in table1, but it doesn't help.

The problem is that I cannot delete inactive records by the company rule

Comment: What kind of Sybase (SAP) DB do you use? IQ, ASE, ASA?

Comment: I have ASE, 15.5. Let me try separate query

Comment: Actually, I tried separate queries. The same slow. Even if I purge inactive records or select active record to different table, it still takes long time. Yesterday I rebuild one index in table1, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please stop using answers to make comments.  Use the comment function, or edit your question to add additional information.

Comment: Why are you specifying the indexes, as opposed to letting the optimizer chose? Without knowing more about your table and index structure it's going to be hard to help.  You could also try posting the query plan to let us see where things are bogging down.  Maybe you could create views against the large tables that only include the active records, then UNION against the views?

Comment: We must inspect the actual query plan to take a idea and check the real culprit. It can be the join, the union or some odd thing in the schema.

it's not likely the union. It merely matches the records from both selects (well, it can be the union, in a special case where it ill do some implicit cast to match columns from selects...i guess that can be tested with a UNION ALL)

It, in general, bad indexing on the join match.

Please post the query plan for a further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem isn't the union, but rather the join with a table that has 65 million rows in it (twice).  If you are certain the union is your problem, why not just make two separate queries?

You could also add new tables to hold the inactive records and purge the active record tables.  I don't know what other application logic you have, but that would speed up this query.